# Can I have Rails 3 save production logs for 90 days?

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-3.2, production-environment, log-rotation

Rails 3 appears to automatically truncate production logs after some unknown period. I would like to be able to save production logs for up to the past 90 days in order to be able to audit the behavior of my app. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8107549/revisions), the old Rails `Logger` supported at least separating logs into different days, if not deleting the old ones automatically, but Rails now uses `BufferedLogger` which doesn't support these options.

Either way, it looks like I may have to resort to configuring Unix's `logrotate` to get the log retention policy I want. That's fine by me, but I'll also have to prevent Rails from automatically truncating the log so that I don't lose anything, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Is there an alternative logging facility for use with Rails (perhaps a gem) which can handle this all in one place? And if not, how do I prevent `BufferedLogger` from truncating logs so it doesn't get in `logrotate`'s way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no truncation at all. BufferedLogger source does not show any limiting of the log file.

And http://engineering.freeagent.com/2011/10/12/understanding-the-rails-logger/ is a good guide to some internals. But it does seem you need to do the rotation yourself.

Comment: Actually, when I used `less` on my production.log, it reported that it appeared to be a binary file. The tail of the file is just a few recent requests, and the head is filled with tons of `^@`... What the heck is that? I've never seen that before...

Comment: I accepted your answer. It turned out my problem had to do with a monkey-patch on BufferedLogger I'd left in from a previous Rails version.